# UIDatePicker will not scroll Day or Month

Tags: xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

Adding a DatePicker with the following code, I can scroll the year but not the Day or Month. Any ideas?

```
datePicker = new UIDatePicker(pickerRect);
datePicker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Date;
datePicker.SetDate(appDelegate.store.builderPlan.p_startDateTime, true);    
datePicker.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleDimensions;
datePicker.ValueChanged += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SetDate();
        };
this.AddSubview(datePicker);
```

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 1):

The picker was hanging outside the view, so no events passed to the view...